# npm package as amqp client helper

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, ecmascript-8

I would like to build a common helper for my application that will manage all the amqplib calls from all of my nodeJS microservices.

I would like to import my amqplibHelper to every microservice and use only my helper commands that they will call internally to the amqplib node.js library so I will be able to use different library in the future of to make changes regarding the amqp commands more easily in one central place.

I created a new npm package for that and tried to write something from scratch but since I don't have too much experience in amqp. I am looking for a "bootstrap" or a template as starting point.

I started with this but I feel I am not going in the right way.

```
class commonAmqp {
   amqp = require('amqplib');      
   connection = start();

   constructor(rabbitmqClientm, validQueues) {
      this.rabbitmqClient = rabbitmqClient;
      this.validQueues = validQueues;

      const { queuesLocal, queuesRemote } = rabbitmqClient;
      const isLocal = queuesLocal.includes(queue);
      const isRemote = queuesRemote.includes(queue);
   }


   async initQueue(queue, data) {
      if (!validQueues.includes(queue)) throw HttpError(g.f('Not valid queue'));

      const { connection, queue } = this;
      const valid = queueValidator(queue, data);
      const channel = connection.then(conn => (conn.createChannel()));

      if (!channel || !valid)
        throw new Error('Not valid queue || queue-data');

      channel.then(function(ch) {
        return ch.assertQueue(queue).then(function(ok) {
          return ch.sendToQueue(queue, new Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(data)));
        });
      });

    };


    async start() {      

      const connection = await this.amqp.connect(rabbitmqClient.url);
      console.log('Connected to RabbitMQ-server');

      connection.on('error', (err) => {
         console.log('rabbitmq-err', err);
         setTimeout(start, 2000);
      });

      connection.on('close', () => {
         console.log('rabbitmq-connection closed');
         setTimeout(start, 5000);
      });

      return connection;       
    }

    config(config) {
       this.config = config;
       console.log('config: ' + this.config);
    }

 }

 module.exports = {
   commonAmqp   
};
```